# Search::Elasticsearch perl module issues with special characters during search

Tags: perl, elasticsearch, kibana

I have written the following query in Kibana interface to search for a comment that has some special characters.

```
GET index01/_search 
{ 
  "query" : { 
    "bool" : { 
      "must" : [ 
        { 
          "match" : { 
            "myattrs.comment" : {
              "query" : "hè testä",
              "operator" : "AND"
            }
          }
        },
        { "range" : { 
          "myattrs.creation_datetime" : { 
            "gte" : "2020-01-01T00:00:00", 
            "lte" : "2021-09-07T23:59:59" 
          }
        }
        }
      ]
      
    } 
  }
}
```

The above query works fine, and I get the desired results.

I am using "Search::Elasticsearch" Perl module, that provides wrapper towards Elasticsearch.  Using this module, I am writing the same query as follows:

$e->search(index => $index_name, body  => "{ $params }" );

where params contains the above query.

When I run it, I get the following error in apache log:

```
'Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x20'
```

and further, I can see that the string is converted to hex-format.

```
{"query" : "h\xe8 test\xe4","operator" : "AND"}
```

Is there a way to avoid this hexadecimal conversion done automatically by the Search::Elasticsearch module?  I presume, if it is possible, the search will give desired results as they were in the first case from Kibana console.

Comment: "\xe8" is Latin-1 (iso-8859-1) encoding of  "è". Can you try to encode the field as UTF-8 instead? See [this](https://pastebin.com/XkDP5UAZ) example. It might be as simple as adding a `use utf8;` to your script

Comment: I have tried adding 'use utf8;' but issue is still there, I think, the issue is when Search::Elasticsearch module creates a json record for the given query, there some conversion is done towards hex format and I don't know how to avoid that.

Comment: Can you include the complete perl script in your question? This will help clarify this issue. See also [mcve]